# OneDrive for Business :"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type

Tags: asp.net, onedrive

I'm trying to integrate the OneDrive for Busines to a Web Form App.
For this I use the documentation given at [this url](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm)
In web Form App I have two Pages:
First one is Login page which have a button for login
On login button click I create a GET Request to OneDrive for Business API using the following code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            Redirecturi = Uri.EscapeDataString(Redirecturi);
            string url = string.Format("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}", ClienId, Redirecturi);
            var response = client.GetAsync(url);
            var json = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Label2.Text = json.Result;
```

When I click the login button it takes me to micorosoft login service and sends me back to `callback.aspx` page with access code (Redirect URI configured on azure)

I got the access code.
On the second page I redeem the access code and make a POST request to get the Authentication token.
Here is the code for the second page:

```
private string BaseUri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token";
    public string Redirecturi = "http://localhost:51642/CallBack.aspx";
    public string ResourcesId = "https://api.office.com/discovery/";
    private string ClienId = "180c6ac4-5829-468e-.....-822405804862"; ///truncated//azure 
    private string ClientSecert = "G4TAQzD8d7C4...OE6m366afv8XKbTCcyXr4=";//truncated
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString[OAuthConstants.AccessToken]))
        {
            // There is a token available already. It should be the token flow. Ignore it.
            return;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString[OAuthConstants.Code]))
        {
            string _accessCode = Request.QueryString[OAuthConstants.Code];
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
           // BaseUri = Uri.EscapeDataString(BaseUri);
            Redirecturi = Uri.EscapeDataString(Redirecturi);
            ResourcesId = Uri.EscapeDataString(ResourcesId);
            string url = string.Format("{0}?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret={3}&code={4}&grant_type=authorization_code&resource={5}", BaseUri, ClienId, Redirecturi, ClientSecert, _accessCode, ResourcesId);
            var response = client.PostAsync(url, null);
            var json = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Response.Write(json);
        }
    }
```

But instead of Response I am get the following error. Which say include the `grant_type` in url. I have already added (you can check in code).
I get same error the same error without including it.

**Here is the error**

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: 2adb3a7f-ceb1-4978-97c4-3dc2d3cc3ad4\r\nCorrelation ID: 29fb11a0-c602-4891-9299-b0b538d75b5f\r\nTimestamp: 2015-07-15 09:58:42Z","error_codes":[90014],"timestamp":"2015-07-15 09:58:42Z","trace_id":"2adb3a7f-ceb1-4978-97c4-3dc2d3cc3ad4","correlation_id":"29fb11a0-c602-4891-9299-b0b538d75b5f","submit_url":null,"context":null}
```

Please help to know where or what is getting wrong.
Any kind of help will be appreciable

Comment: Ever figured this out? Because I'm having the same problem trying to access the endpoint using Java

Answer (score 6):

You're adding the parameters to the request querystring. You have to post the data in the request body.

```
var content = new StringContent(
                "grant_type=authorization_code" +
                "&client_id=" + ClienId +
                "&redirect_uri=" + Redirecturi +
                "&client_secret=" + ClientSecert +
                "&code=" + _accessCode +
                "&resource=" + ResourcesId,
                Encoding.UTF8, 
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var response = httpClient.PostAsync(BaseUri, content);

var result = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: I am Using the Post Man in Google Chrome, i am also geting same Error

Comment: Sunil> In the Post Man in Google Chrome need:
1) add header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
2) then remove all spaces among body parameters!

Answer (score 3):

use FormUrlEncodedContent instead of StringContent (form data post)

```
var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "client_id", clientId },
    { "client_secret", clientSecret },
    { "code", authCode },
    { "redirect_uri", redirectUri },
    { "grant_type", "authorization_code" }
});

var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", formContent);
```

Comment: whats wrong with FormUrlEncodedContent instead of StringContent? You do not need to define the enconding type yourself and you are able to pass key value pairs instead of concating the strings yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> Sharing for future readers because this error is not specific to OneDrive only but can arise in other Microsoft tools

I was getting this error when working with [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://dev.botframework.com/)'s [Skype bot](https://dev.skype.com/bots). In my case the bot file [the `appId` and `appSecret` was wrongly set to `clientId` and `clientSecret`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/335#issuecomment-407004750)

Changing the same to `appId` and `appSecret` fixed the issue.