# oauth2 error AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

Tags: http, oauth-2.0, bearer-token, windev

From the development in Windev I use Oauth 2.0 for authorization to get access to the outlook mail from a user.

The application is registered at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com without the Implicit workflow.
After the user enters the credentials, an Authorization Code is returned.
With the new code the Bearer Token is requested with a HTTP Post command.

So far, so good.

Only that the response gives an error message that makes no sense to me.

In code:

```
m_sHTTPUrl = "client_id=" + m_sClientID + "&client_secret=" ...
    + m_sClientSecret ...
    + "&redirect_uri=" + m_sRedirectURL + "&code=" + m_sAuthToken ...
    + "&grant_type=authorization_code"
m_sHTTPres = ""
LogLocalFile("GetAccessToken - " + m_sTokenURL + " // " + m_sHTTPUrl) 

cMyRequest is httpRequest
cMyRequest..Method = httpPost
cMyRequest..URL = m_sTokenURL
cMyRequest..ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
cMyRequest..Header["grant_type"] = "authorization_code"
cMyRequest..Header["code"] = m_sAuthToken
cMyRequest..Header["client_id"] = m_sClientID
cMyRequest..Header["client_secret"] = m_sClientSecret
cMyRequest..Header["scope"] = m_sScope
cMyRequest..Header["redirect_uri"] = m_sRedirectURL
//cMyRequest..Content = m_sHTTPUrl
cMyResponse is httpResponse = HTTPSend(cMyRequest)
m_sHTTPres = cMyResponse.Content
```

In a logfile I requested the used parameters and the content of the httpResponse:

```
GetAccessToken - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token // grant_type=authorization_code
&code=xxxxxxx
&scope=openid+offline_access+User.Read+Email+Mail.Read+Contacts.Read
&redirect_uri=http://localhost/
&client_id=xxxxxxx
&client_secret=xxxxxxx

GetAccessToken - error = invalid_request
GetAccessToken - error_description = AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.
```

The grant_type is in the header as it is supposed to be.

Does anybody have any clue of what is needed to get the OAUTH2 working ?

Comment: According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430855/onedrive-for-business-invalid-request-error-descriptionaadsts90014-the-r) the oauth-2.0 parameters must be in the content of your request. Did you already try it ?
This [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d54c668f-d8e3-4662-b124-d9abc3176c8c/http-post-body-parameters-to-get-oauth2-token?forum=azurelogicapps) warns also on the encoding of the body.

Comment: Thanx for the direction.
a) It has to be in the body, not in the header.
b) It has to be encoded, in plain text.
Than it works.

Answer (score 30):

You shouldn't send `grant_type` neither in params nor in headers. Those should be sent in **body params** then only it will work.

Url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`
`client_id`, `scope` and `redirect_uri` params can be sent as query params.
where as `grant_type`, `code` and `client_secret` should sent in body params.

```
grant_type:authorization_code, 
code: {code you got from the authorization step}, 
client_secret: ****
```

Comment: To convert params to formdata - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630754/1481519

Comment: client_id, scope and redirect_uri must also be sent in the body

Comment: my god this service is such a turd!

Comment: Read [this](https://gist.github.com/akexorcist/ea93ee47d39cf94e77802bc39c46589b) if you are using axios to create the params properly. All of the params went in this way and it worked for me.

Comment: Converting the params to formdata worked for me!

Comment: that's funny because I had to change it to `x-www-form-urlencoded` to get it working. In the header I have content-type set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 29):

You need to pass everything in body as `form-data`:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--form 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--form '<the code you have got from the authorization endpoint' \
--form 'client_secret=****' \
--form 'client_id=********' \
--form 'scope=m_sScope' \
--form 'redirect_uri=http://localhost/'
```

Comment: Does this also apply to the auth part? I am getting this error at the authorize endpoint, which as I understand it, comes before the token endpoint call.

Answer (score 10):

you should change the content type  as : application/x-www-form-urlencoded

the body must to be formated as bellow:

```
 client_id=8cfbe8ac-8775-4c56-9302-k9d5a42cbf98
 &client_secret=BOy7Q~pGvXF.SWshX72mmMnQeAkvN5elHWiYT
 &grant_type=client_credentials
 &resource=https://miurl.com
```

Answer (score 7):

If someone is still having this issue, You can try from postman like below. Please check the Body type as "x-www-form-urlencoded"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this right after referring to multiple answers.

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token
--make sure to enter the ID directly without <,>

Use 'x-www-form-urlencoded' format for the Body.
Enter Keys & Values for the below parameters
client_id - Client_ID on your Azure App
client_secret - client_secret value and not the key. Note that this value is available only for the first time upon the client secret key creation
grant_type - client_credentials (static words, don't try to look for the value)
resource - App ID URI

reference link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/dn645543(v=azure.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

when providing "Default Scope" value must be full name example , "User.Read" correct value can get from azure AD APP -> Api Permission