# Microsoft get access tocken keeps asking me for "grant_type"

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I am trying to get access token with Microsoft graph API.
i am keep getting error -

```
error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'
```

in my post request i added the "grant_type" param, what do i do wrong?

Request: (i put my tenant and edit all the other parameters)

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: 4c3017cc-8624-4921-8cea-794861ca5a00\r\nCorrelation ID: cf5e682c-7522-4be3-a9f3-16bb33f40946\r\nTimestamp: 2022-08-02 10:20:07Z",
    "error_codes": [
        900144
    ],
    "timestamp": "2022-08-02 10:20:07Z",
    "trace_id": "4c3017cc-8624-4921-8cea-794861ca5a00",
    "correlation_id": "cf5e682c-7522-4be3-a9f3-16bb33f40946",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144"
}
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

this worked 4 days ago...
i don't know what

thanks!

Comment: did you try with Postman? In addition there already an question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513122/oauth2-error-aadsts90014-the-request-body-must-contain-the-following-parameter) did you take a look. I would say first try with postman

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't send grant_type neither in params nor in headers. Those should be sent in body params then only it will work.

Url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token client_id, scope and redirect_uri params can be sent as query params. where as grant_type, code and client_secret should sent in body params.

```
grant_type:authorization_code, 
code: {code you got from the authorization step}, 
client_secret: ****
```

Answer (score 0):

The **grant_type** should be passed as **formData**